# Calculating Base-n logarithm in Ruby

Tags: ruby, math, logarithm

This one seems like an easy one, but I'm having trouble calculating log (Base 5) in Ruby.

Clearly the standard base-10 log works fine:

```
>> value = Math::log(234504)
=> 12.3652279242923
```

But in my project I need to use Base 5. According to the ruby docs (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Math.html#M001473) it seems I should be able to do this:

**Math.log(num,base) → float**

```
>> value = Math::log(234504, 5)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
    from (irb):203:in `log'
    from (irb):203
    from :0
```

Which it doesn't like. Anyone know how to calculate logs in base-n in ruby on rails?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you using? Works for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'll check Ruby function but don't forget your basics:
[image]

Prior to Ruby 1.9:

```
> Math::log(234504) / Math::log(5)
=> 7.682948083154834
```

In Ruby 1.9 and later, the second argument was introduced:

```
> Math::log(234504, 5)
=> 7.682948083154834
```

Comment: this works in any base - not just to the base of e. just use the decadic logarithm instead of ln.

Comment: Actually, it' even more general: `log_b1(x) = log_b2(x) / log_b2(b1)` (edit: in relatively plain english, what @Femaref said).

Comment: just couldn't come up with a resonable good notation for the bases.

Comment: Ha, I had avoided dusting off my college textbooks! Thanks, this works great. I'm guessing then that there's no direct support for base-n in the log functions right now.

Comment: Yep, I guess we should feel happy with that solution but I cannot be fully satisfied. Which version do you have?

Comment: Thanks steenslag - looks like it might be time for me to upgrade my Ruby.

Answer (score 4):

The other answer is correct of course, but in the interest of saving time, `Math.log(n, base)` works in Ruby >= 1.9

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Math.html#method-c-log

Comment: I +1'd you because it's much more Rubyish, but if you look into `log(x, base)` source code, you'll see that it just winds up using the same relation: `d = log(d0); if (argc == 2) d /= log(RFLOAT_VALUE(base));`.
So, using one call to function that anyway deals with arbitrary base is more efficient - it does one function call instead of two.